# Process Woocommerce API using PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce-rest-api

Is it possible to process woocommrce api using curl?
I am trying to do it but no success. This api works in insomnia or postman

**To Process**

```
curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```

**Following is what I am doing**

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products
$Consumer_Key="ck_111111";
$Consumer_Secret= "cs_222222";


$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $Consumer_Key.":".$Consumer_Secret
);

$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// Execute request, store response and HTTP response code
$response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

**And The error I am getting is**

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Forbidden could simply mean that the CK and CS are invalid or have been corrupted, due to cache or some other header mangling..

Comment: 403 Forbidden could mean a lot of things. If I were you, I will add User Agent to the header and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand a lot of PHP but I have the same code working well on Angular with the cURL:

```
getCategories() {
this.http.get(this.cUrl + "/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?per_page=100&consumer_key=" + this.wooApiClie + "&consumer_secret=" + this.wooApiSec).subscribe(res => {
  this.categories = res;
  console.log(this.categories);
})
```

This one is for the categories but it's the same for the products. Maybe it's because your variables `$Consumer_key` and `$Consumer_secret` are in caps? I repeat, I don't understand too much of PHP.